# ajax - Div text not changing

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, html

I'm a newbie in AJAX and so I am facing a lot of problems in making a simple AJAX program. I have a button on which I want to do is that when I will click it the text of the div below it changes. I tried so much times but still couldn't find the bug.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
        function loadXMLDoc() {
            var xmlhttp;

            if(!window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } else {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }

            xmlhttp.onReadyStateChange = function () {
                if(xmlhttp.readyState==2 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                    document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            };

            xmlhttp.open('GET', 'textfile.txt', true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" value="Click!" onClick="loadXMLDoc();">Hello World</button>
    <div id='myDiv'>hello!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the text file:

```
<p>My name is areeb siddiqui</p>
<p>My name is areeb siddiqui</p>
```

**Any help would be appreciated**

**Thanks in advance :)**

Also here is my webpage : http://mytestingsite.site90.net/ajax/

Comment: `readyState == 2` ?? Should be 4... http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20060405/#dfn-readystate

Comment: what's the problem in using jquery or some thing like it?

Comment: I changed it but still not working! :/

Comment: @Abu no I first want to do pure AJAX! :)

Comment: but why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: it's beacuse I am a newbie! :) @Abu

Comment: use a full library just for an ajax request? IMHO it's good to understand how these things work rather than just using jQuery.

Comment: yeah :) that's the reason! @DannyHearnah

Comment: can you please answer? @DannyHearnah

Comment: @AreebSiddiqui i have answered for you

Comment: FYI: `onreadystatechange` should be all lowercase.. unlike a lot of JaVaScRiPt

Comment: Try giving full path to the txt file you are accessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.. this is how i make my ajax requests.. so very similar

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xmlhttp = null;

    if(!window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'textfile.txt', true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState != 4 || xmlhttp.status != 200){return;}
        document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }

}
```

The reason your function was not updating is because `onreadystatechange` must be all lowercase

Comment: I bet you are trying to access the textfile.txt locally and not via http.

Comment: @schar that was going to be my second answer.. however you beat me to it (by 2 days) haha

Answer (score 1):

Change this block:

```
if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
```

Comment: I would suggest either doing an alert(xmlhttp.responseText); or console.log(xmlhttp.responseText); and ensure that you are first getting your text returned. But in any case !=2

Comment: its not even alerting! O.o @cliffbarnes

Answer (score 0):

checK onreadystatechange

```
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the onReadyStateChange with onreadystatechange
and xmlhttp.readyState==2 with xmlhttp.readyState==4